# Cannot mask WordPress page URL using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp_test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^the_image$ wp-content/uploads/2019/01/banner\.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^the_page$ sample-page [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I go to `example.com/the_image` it shows the correct image. However, if I go to `the_page` it shows the `page not found` page.

Any work around on this?

Comment: Try to add the RewriteRules directly under `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: @wp78de tried, didn't work